# How to insert values at certain time of a DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a reproducible code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

foo = pd.read_csv("http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1545406250692.txt", header=None, names=["Stock","Date","Time", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "OI"], dtype={"Stock":"category"}, parse_dates= [['Date', 'Time']], index_col="Date_Time")
foo.sort_index(inplace=True)
bar = foo.between_time('09:00:00', '15:30:00') #Dropping post and pre market data i.e. from index 15:31 - 16:35

#resampling the data by 120 Minutes (2 hours)
twohour = bar.loc["2018-11-22 09:08:00":].resample('120Min',closed = 'right',label = 'left', base=75).agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min','Close': 'last'}).dropna()
twohour.head(7)

Out[]:
                    Close   High    Open    Low
Date_Time               
2018-11-22 07:15:00 321.3   321.30  321.30  321.30
2018-11-22 09:15:00 324.5   326.90  320.10  320.00
2018-11-22 11:15:00 323.2   324.85  324.60  322.20
2018-11-22 13:15:00 319.9   324.35  323.20  319.50
2018-11-22 15:15:00 320.0   320.35  319.85  319.15
2018-11-26 07:15:00 324.90  324.90  324.90  324.90
2018-11-26 09:15:00 311.35  324.40  323.10  309.60
```

I want every value in `Open` column in indexes with time `09:15:00` to be replaced with value of `Close` column  in index with time `07:15:00`.

In short, i need this output:

```
Out[]:
                    Close   High    Open    Low
Date_Time               
2018-11-22 07:15:00 321.3   321.30  321.30  321.30
2018-11-22 09:15:00 324.5   326.90  321.30  320.00
2018-11-22 11:15:00 323.2   324.85  324.60  322.20
2018-11-22 13:15:00 319.9   324.35  323.20  319.50
2018-11-22 15:15:00 320.0   320.35  319.85  319.15
2018-11-26 07:15:00 324.90  324.90  324.90  324.90
2018-11-26 09:15:00 311.35  324.40  324.90  309.60
```

I tried using `.loc` by converting `DateTimeindex` to dictionaries and then replacing the values. but the dictionaries werent sorted, so it needs the dict get sorted and the code gets more and more ugly. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your DataFrame, there are two rows in which the 'Date_Time' column value is '07:15:00'. How do you decide which of these to choose when substituting?

Comment: And what should happen on the date where you have Data for 9:15 but not a record for 7:15?

Comment: @L.B. i want to substitute with the one which is above the index with time 9:15:00 as shown in the output.

Comment: @ALollz this wont happen but if it does, i dont want to change anything, i will keep the data as it is.

Comment: In this case, I believe that Vaishali's answer might work for you. Have you tried it?

Comment: I mean it **does** happen on 2018-11-28 in your provided data. But good to know how to deal with it.

Comment: @L.B. not yet, gonna try in next 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your index to `timdelta` *or* strings before comparison:

```
# timedelta option, vectorised & efficient
mask_bool = (df.index - df.index.normalize()) == '09:15:00'

# string alternative, inefficient
mask_bool = df.index.strftime('%H:%M') == '09:15'
```

Then assign via `loc` or `mask`:

```
# Option 1: assign conditionally via loc
df.loc[mask_bool, 'Open'] = df['Close'].shift(1)

# Option 2: mask with pd.Series.mask
df['Open'] = df['Open'].mask(mask_bool, df['Close'].shift(1))
```

Result:

```
print(df)

                      Close    High    Open     Low
Date_Time                                          
2018-11-22 07:15:00  321.30  321.30  321.30  321.30
2018-11-22 09:15:00  324.50  326.90  321.30  320.00
2018-11-22 11:15:00  323.20  324.85  324.60  322.20
2018-11-22 13:15:00  319.90  324.35  323.20  319.50
2018-11-22 15:15:00  320.00  320.35  319.85  319.15
2018-11-26 07:15:00  324.90  324.90  324.90  324.90
2018-11-26 09:15:00  311.35  324.40  324.90  309.60
```

#### Performance benchmarking

For larger dataframes, the `timedelta` vectorised version should be efficient, but note this will be system and set-up dependent:

```
# Python 3.6.5, Pandas 0.23, NumPy 1.14.3

import pandas as pd
from datetime import time

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Date_Time': ['2018-11-22 07:15:00', '2018-11-22 09:15:00',
                                           '2018-11-22 11:15:00', '2018-11-22 13:15:00',
                                           '2018-11-22 15:15:00', '2018-11-26 07:15:00',
                                           '2018-11-26 09:15:00'],
                             'Close': [321.3, 324.5, 323.2, 319.9, 320.0, 324.9, 311.35],
                             'High': [321.3, 326.9, 324.85, 324.35, 320.35, 324.9, 324.4],
                             'Open': [321.3, 321.3, 324.6, 323.2, 319.85, 324.9, 324.9],
                             'Low': [321.3, 320.0, 322.2, 319.5, 319.15, 324.9, 309.6]})

df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])
df = df.set_index('Date_Time')

df = pd.concat([df]*10**4)

%timeit (df.index - df.index.normalize()) == '09:15:00'  # 8.67 ms
%timeit df.index.strftime('%H:%M') == '09:15'            # 651 ms
%timeit df.index.time == time(9, 15)                     # 28.3 ms
```

Comment: Thank you @jpp. according to you, which answer/code will be faster? yours or Vaishali's answer?

Comment: @ArJuN, See update, timing the Boolean mask bottleneck, the `timedelta` option is best of the 3 for larger dataframes.

Comment: Can you time again with both the lines of code? I am still getting better time using loc

Comment: @Vaishali, I see the same, I have added my full benchmarking code with version numbers, and added a disclaimer too. Benchmarking is, of course, system dependent.

Comment: Its because you are only comparing the code which creates the mask. The bulk of operation happens when you assign the data based on the slice. I checked the time with both the lines of code. Anyway, I was just curious so wanted to see if I was missing something.

Comment: @Vaishali, Ah I see. Yes, there are multiple ways to do the other part, `loc`, `np.where`, `mask`, etc. You might be right about the choice of indexing method.

Answer (score 4):

You can select desired rows using loc and set the Open column to close.shift

```
import datetime 

df.loc[df.index.time == datetime.time(9, 15), 'Open'] = df['Close'].shift(1)


                    Close   High    Open    Low
Date_Time               
2018-11-22 07:15:00 321.30  321.30  321.30  321.30
2018-11-22 09:15:00 324.50  326.90  321.30  320.00
2018-11-22 11:15:00 323.20  324.85  324.60  322.20
2018-11-22 13:15:00 319.90  324.35  323.20  319.50
2018-11-22 15:15:00 320.00  320.35  319.85  319.15
2018-11-26 07:15:00 324.90  324.90  324.90  324.90
2018-11-26 09:15:00 311.35  324.40  324.90  309.60
```

Edit: Comparing time

```
import time
start = time.clock()
df.loc[df.index.time == datetime.time(9, 15), 'Open'] = df['Close'].shift(1)
print (time.clock() - start)

0.006845999999999464


start = time.clock()
mask_bool = (df.index - df.index.normalize()) == '09:15:00'
df['Open'] = df['Open'].mask(mask_bool, df['Close'].shift(1))
print (time.clock() - start)

0.009392999999999319
```

Comment: `datetime.time(9, 15)` doesn't seem to work, does it? Error: `TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'`

Comment: @zyxue Need `import datetime` not `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: You need to import datetime

Comment: @Vaishali Thanks a lot for the answer. but i ran the code by replacing `df` with `twohour` but strangely i cant see any changes on the output. can you insert reproducible code please?

Comment: @Vaishali, sorry forgot to replace all `df`. the code is working perfectly. thanks again!

Comment: @ArJuN, I just added the time comparison

Comment: @Vaishali Thanks for the comparison. i just checked by myself which code is faster and found that jpp's answer faster by 40ms when using large dataframe. dont know how. but i appreciate your help and i upvoted your answer.